# Why am i getting extra indentation-steps on react-router render function?

Tags: indentation, web-mode

I am trying to write a school project in React with react-router v4 in web-mode. When i try to write the render props function web-mode inserts 4 spaces instead of the desired 2.

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={'/home'}
    render={ (props) => (
        <Home {...props} />  <--- 4 spaces
      )} />                  <--- this should be aligned with the 'r'
</Switch>
```

web-mode-code/markup/css-indentaion-offset are all set to 2.

This becomes a hugh pain both mentally and because of eslint rules that we use.

Answer (score 1):

The version 14.1.17 of web-mode solves those two issues : https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode